# How can I remove header names when joining files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried using numpy.concatonate as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658478/pandas-concatenate-files-but-skip-the-headers-except-the-first-file) post suggests

The files I'm working on originally look like this.

```
>>> df = pd.read_html(file)
>>> df.head()
            0            1                        2
0          Id         Date                   Reason
1         161  04-Mar-2019                Cancelled
2         843  04-Mar-2019                Cancelled
3         042  04-Mar-2019                Cancelled
4         247  04-Mar-2019                Cancelled
```

This is my code, the csv file it spits out still has the column names where the files have been joined.

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(path + "Export*"+ extension))
all_data = []
if len(files) == 1: # check if there's only 1 file
    df = pd.read_html(files[0])[0]
    df.to_csv(path + filename + ".csv", index=False, header=False)

first = files.pop(-1) # order the files
files.insert(0, first)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_html(file)[0]
    all_data.append(df.values)       


df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(all_data), columns=pd.read_html(first)[0].columns)
df.to_csv(path + filename + ".csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not reading your files in as you think you are; `first[0].columns` is actually `['0', '1', '2']` not `['Id', 'Date', 'Reason']` (as you'd like it to be).

Without the columns identified correctly, your call to

```
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(all_data), columns=pd.read_html(first[0].columns))
```

isn't going to behave as you'd like it.

When you read in the data with `read_html` you'll want to ensure you specify where the column names are located in the file. You can do this with the `header` argument.

So, you're probably going to want to read in your data as something like `df = pd.read_html(file, header=1)`.

After being read in your data should look like this.

```
df.head()
    Id         Date     Reason
1  161  04-Mar-2019  Cancelled
2  843  04-Mar-2019  Cancelled
3   42  04-Mar-2019  Cancelled
4  247  04-Mar-2019  Cancelled
```

With this, the result of your concatenation should be as you desire.